# How to access my bitbucket repository if I rename it

Tags: git

I have a git project on bit bucket which I access via:

```
git@bitbucket.org:amm/witmachine.git
```

I would like to access as:

```
git@bitbucket.org:amm/masterwit.git
```

Do I need to create a new repository?

I have an existing checkout - if I rename the repository how to I make my checkout use the correct project on bitbucket instead of the old one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So you want to change the URL of a remote?

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:amm/masterwit.git
```

Comment: just need to rename project git. the repository is the same, would have to change in bitbucket. thanks.

Comment: @AntonioM.Mérida: … what? What do you need to change? The BitBucket project name?

Comment: yes, Is it better to create a new repository?, and delete the current one?.

Comment: @AntonioM.Mérida: No. If you renamed the repository, no need to recreate it.

Comment: ok, I changed the name of the project in **bitbucket** and I modified the file `.git/config`. thanks @minitech and @AD7six.